# How to use pdf document in the agent using Langchain

Tags: python, langchain, large-language-model, pdfium

My code uses "wikipedia" to search for the relevant content. Below is the code

## Load tools

```
tools = load_tools(
    ["wikipedia"],
    llm=llm)
agent = initialize_agent(
    tools,
    llm,
    agent=AgentType.CHAT_ZERO_SHOT_REACT_DESCRIPTION,
    handle_parsing_errors=True,
    verbose=False
)
out = agent(f"Does {var_1} cause {var_2} or the other way around?.")
```

Instead of "wikipedia", I want to use my own pdf document that is available in my local. Can anyone help me in doing this?

I have tried using the below code

```
from langchain.document_loaders import PyPDFium2Loader
loader = PyPDFium2Loader("hunter-350-dual-channel.pdf")
data = loader.load()
```

but i am not sure how to include this in the agent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use RetrievalQA to generate a tool.

Just like below:

```
from langchain.agents import AgentType, Tool, initialize_agent
from langchain.agents import load_tools
from langchain.chains import RetrievalQA
from langchain.embeddings.openai import OpenAIEmbeddings
from langchain.llms import OpenAI
from langchain.text_splitter import CharacterTextSplitter
from langchain.vectorstores import Chroma
from langchain.document_loaders import TextLoader

llm = OpenAI()

loader = TextLoader("union.txt", encoding="utf-8")
documents = loader.load()
text_splitter = CharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=1000, chunk_overlap=0)
texts = text_splitter.split_documents(documents)

embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings(api_key="sk-pIgio******************", base_url="https://api.gptapi.us/v1")
docsearch = Chroma.from_documents(texts, embeddings, collection_name="state-of-union")

state_of_union = RetrievalQA.from_chain_type(
    llm=llm, chain_type="stuff", retriever=docsearch.as_retriever()
)

tools = load_tools(["wikipedia"], llm=llm)
tools += [
    Tool(
        name="State of Union QA System",
        func=state_of_union.run,
        description="useful for when you need to answer questions about the most recent state of the union address. Input should be a fully formed question.",
    ),   
]

agent = initialize_agent(
    tools, llm, agent=AgentType.ZERO_SHOT_REACT_DESCRIPTION, verbose=True
)
agent.run(
    "What did biden say about ketanji brown jackson in the state of the union address?"
)
```

Comment: Hi. Is there anyway to use HuggingFaceEmbeddings instead of open ai embeddings?

Comment: Sure！
`from langchain.embeddings import OpenAIEmbeddings, HuggingFaceBgeEmbeddings
embeddings = HuggingFaceBgeEmbeddings(model_name="BAAI/bge-large-en-v1.5")
`